# Flutter. How to better organize an exchange with the server, when the Internet is not stable?

Tags: flutter, dart, scheduled-tasks

The user enters data in the application. And this data should be sent to the server.
But the user works in places where the Internet is not always available. So, when the device is offline, the data must be stored locally.

And as soon as the Internet appears, the data must be sent to the server, even when the application is closed.

What is the best way to organize such an algorithm so as not to drain the device's battery?

Comment: You can store data locally and listen to network status using connectivity_plus package. Once there is network connection and data in local, then push to server

Comment: @Uvais But then I need to check the availability of the Internet with the help of which task scheduler. Won't that drain the battery too much?

Comment: @ОлександрЛисак you should only push the data to the server when the app is open. So when the app is opened by the user, check for internet, and if internet is available then synch the app with the server. It would probably be a good idea to present a notification that this is happening as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [workmanager](https://pub.dev/packages/workmanager) package.According to [flutter documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/packages-and-plugins/background-processes), it enables persistent background processing that keeps tasks scheduled through app restarts and system reboots.

In this package, you can use like this.

```
Workmanager().registerOneOffTask(
  "task-identifier",
  simpleTaskKey, // Ignored on iOS
  initialDelay: Duration(minutes: 30),
  constraints: Constraints(
    // connected or metered mark the task as requiring internet
    networkType: NetworkType.connected,
    // require external power
    requiresCharging: true,
  ),
  inputData: ... // fully supported
);
```

The `constraints` property can be used for specifying when should the function trigger.

This [blog](https://medium.com/@yonatanvlevin/the-minimum-interval-for-periodicwork-is-15-minutes-same-as-jobscheduler-periodic-job-eb2d63716d1f) may help to understand which is the best method for saving battery.